# Почему при использовании DOMParser мой код выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: javascript, dom

Недавно начал изучать JavaScript. Столкнулся с заданием, где требуется перевести заданную xml-строку в JASON-строку. Решил действовать через DOMParser() и JASON.stringify(). У меня получился вот такой код:

```js
const xmlString = `<list>
  <student>
    <name lang="en">
      <first>Ivan</first>
      <second>Ivanov</second>
    </name>
    <age>35</age>
    <prof>teacher</prof>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name lang="ru">
      <first>Петр</first>
      <second>Петров</second>
    </name>
    <age>58</age>
    <prof>driver</prof>
  </student>
</list>`;
const DP = new DOMParser();
const domObj = DP.parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');
const jasonString = JSON.stringify(domObj);
console.log(jasonString);
```

Объясните мне пожалуйста, почему этот код возвращает в результате:

```
"{'location':null}"
```

хотя я ожидаю увидеть данные, хранящиеся в xmlString, преобразованные в формат JASON?
Как мне исправить ошибку?

Comment: Как `XML` превратится в строку формата `JSON`? Т.е. какую строку ты в итоге ожидаешь увидеть?

Comment: Потому что `.parseFromString()` возвращает или [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) или [XMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument), как в Вашем случае.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/convert-xml-to-json-and-back-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я ожидаю увидеть данные, хранящиеся в xmlString, преобразованные в формат JASON?

Твоя команда

```
const jasonString = JSON.stringify(domObj)
```

совсем не имеет смысла...

> Как мне исправить ошибку?

Предложу такой вариант решения этой проблемы.

```js
const xmlString = `<list>
  <student>
    <name lang="en">
      <first>Ivan</first>
      <second>Ivanov</second>
    </name>
    <age>35</age>
    <prof>teacher</prof>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name lang="ru">
      <first>Петр</first>
      <second>Петров</second>
    </name>
    <age>58</age>
    <prof>driver</prof>
  </student>
</list>`;
const DP = new DOMParser();
const dom = DP.parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');
const a = [...dom.querySelectorAll('student')].map(o => ({
  name: {
    first: o.querySelector('first').textContent, 
    second: o.querySelector('second').textContent
  },
  age: o.querySelector('age').textContent,
  prof: o.querySelector('prof').textContent
}))
const json = JSON.stringify(a);
console.log(json);
```